# Program freezes after iterating loop - excel vba for loop

Tags: vba, excel, do-while

I am trying to use iteration to solve an equation of acceleration;

```
a =((T * IE * i1 * ef1) / rdyn) - ((((IE + IT) * ((ifinal * i1) ^ 2) + 
IW) * a0) / ((rdyn) ^ 2)) - (mF * g * fR * Cos(Atn(0))) - (mF * g * 
Sin(Atn(0))) - (0.5 * ro * cW * A * ((V) ^ 2) / ((3.6) ^ 2));
```

in which i am using a0 for the iteration value and a for the future value. I used a do while loop , the program is pretty simple. I found out that it takes about 3 or 4 iterations to converge to a value. The problem is, when it calculates the final value excel freezes.

I cant seem to find the problem. Could anyone spot what might be wrong please?

```
    Sub IteracaoAceleracao()

Dim FZA, inertia, Rollresist, FSt, FL, T, ifinal, i1, ef1, rdyn, IE, IT, IW, mF, g, fR, ro, cW, A, V, a0, e, c As Double

a0 = 0
e = 1
c = 0

T = Sheets("T.Pot x n DADOS").Range("C5")
ifinal = Sheets("Dados carro.motor.transm").Range("D21")
i1 = Sheets("Dados carro.motor.transm").Range("D16")
ef1 = Sheets("Dados carro.motor.transm").Range("E16")
rdyn = Sheets("Dados carro.motor.transm").Range("D5")
IE = Sheets("Dados carro.motor.transm").Range("J4")
IT = Sheets("Dados carro.motor.transm").Range("J5")
IW = Sheets("Dados carro.motor.transm").Range("J3")
mF = Sheets("Dados carro.motor.transm").Range("D2")
g = 9.81
fR = Sheets("T.Pot x n DADOS").Range("A36")
ro = Sheets("Dados carro.motor.transm").Range("D25")
cW = Sheets("Dados carro.motor.transm").Range("D3")
A = Sheets("Dados carro.motor.transm").Range("D4")
V = Sheets("T.Pot x n DADOS").Range("A22")
FZA = (T * ifinal* i1 * ef1) / rdyn
inertia = (((IE + IT) * ((ifinal * i1) ^ 2) + IW) * a0) / ((rdyn) ^ 2)
Rollresist = mF * g * fR * Cos(Atn(0))
FSt = mF * g * Sin(Atn(0))
FL = 0.5 * ro * cW * A * ((V) ^ 2) / ((3.6) ^ 2)

Do While e > 0.00155


Sheets("FZ,Ex aceleração").Range("L4") = (FZA - inertia - Rollresist - FSt - FL) / mF

e = Sheets("FZ,Ex aceleração").Range("L4") - ax0
e = Abs(e)
a0 = Sheets("FZ,Ex aceleração").Range("L4")

Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: FYI `Dim FZA, inertia, Rollresist, FSt, FL, T, ifinal, i1, ef1, rdyn, IE, IT, IW, mF, g, fR, ro, cW, A, V, a0, e, c As Double` declares `c` as a `Double`, and everything else is an implicit `Variant`.

Answer (score 0):

The ax0 in line 35 looks pretty suspicious

`e = Sheets("FZ,Ex aceleraçao").Range("L4") - ax0`.

Maybe it should be

`e = Sheets("FZ,Ex aceleraçao").Range("L4") - a0`.

The code is very unreadable. Do stuff like:

```
Dim a0 as Double
Const g as Double = 9.81
Dim shDados as Worksheet    
Set shDados = Sheets("Dados carro.motor.transm") 
ifinal = shDados.range("D21")
```

etc...

I hope this helps you. Keep up the good work.

Comment: Oh, yes, it is about ax0,  somehow always the last mistakes are the most simple ones, haha thanks